# LoRaWAN wireless dongle not responding to AT command

Tags: serial-port

0
down vote
favorite

I want to configure a wireless LoRaWAN dongle via AT commands by using the echo command in the ubuntu terminal but the dongle doesn't seems to be responding with any feedback messages at all. After echoing the following command line, the terminal just go on to a new line without any messages / prompts.

echo 'AAT1 FwVersion' > /dev/ttyAMC0

(I performed a dmesg operation, the wireless dongle is in /dev/ttyACM0. No linux driver is provided for this wireless dongle but it can be configured via serial connection using AT commands.)

Am i sending AT command to the dongle the right way?

Comment: Cross-posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51650135/lorawan-wireless-dongle-not-responding-to-at-command?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You would not get a response this way.

But if you also don't get a prompt, that means that the echo blocks, the device isn't accepting input at all.